# mysql delete/insert vs. update

Tags: mysql

I have tried to find thoughts on this, but can't find quite what I am looking for.

In one topic on here, people seemed to agree that "almost" all of the time, an update would be much preferable to deleting a row and re-inserting it.

HOWEVER, my situation is which would be better between doing several hundred individual updates vs. 1 mass delete and 1 bulk insert for those hundreds of rows.

Wouldn't all of the time saved from doing the bulk insert more than offset the extra work from doing the delete/insert method vs. update?

No other table needs the ids from these rows, by the way.

Comment: I forgot to add that I also read that a concern is fragmenting over time.

Comment: When in doubt, profile.

Comment: Why not simply issue a mass update instead?

Comment: What I do in cases like this is insert into a temporary table, then do an update+join to merge the temporary table into the permanent table.

Comment: offering us a bit more info about what you are inserting would greatly benefit this question.  it would seem that if you have all of the data you need to do a mass insert, you might as well do a mass update - but then there is some speculation in comments below about why.  you can eliminate this ambiguity by providing more detail

Comment: @billynoah I am doing it with a framework where I don't think I can do a mass update where each row needs different values, but I am looking into it.

Comment: a framework provides tools to get things done but shouldn't limit you in that way.  if you have needs that aren't met by the tools in hand, you need to extend the framework to fit your needs, not contort your approach to fit inside the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer would depend on the exact update/delete query you are trying to run, and on the data.  But, in general I would expect that just doing an update would be faster than deleting and re-inserting.  The reason is that very similar lookup logic will have to run in either approach to target the records in question.  In the case of delete/insert, you would then remove those records and bulk insert.  However, in the case of update, you would have already found the records, and would just need to mutate some data.

Comment: I suspect his issue is that there's no common logic to all the updates. He has a large set of new values that want to replace the old values.

Comment: @Barmar Then maybe my blanket answer is not appropriate.  We know in general that most of the time deleting then reinserting is not done instead of updates.

Comment: yes the situation is that the rows being updated don't have anything common to them, such as needing to update the same column to the same value or something=something+1. And I've learned what I know of php and MySQL by looking at examples and asking questions, so there's still a lot of the "behind the scenes" stuff I don't thoroughly understand. I wasn't even doing bulk inserts anywhere at all until someone recommended that.

Comment: Well the issue still is that delete requires a lookup.  And after that I'm not sure that bulk inserting new records would be faster than updating certain columns in records which are already in the database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen even when doing a delete where something=1 and the column something is indexed, you'd still have concerns there? (again, I don't know much about efficiency of various actions, such as how much slower one is than another).

Comment: OK, but then wouldn't an update also be just as fast?

Comment: I'm doing a third party app and working within their framework and I don't "think" they have a setup where I could update multiple rows at once with different values for each row. I could look further in case I am overlooking something, but I think it would mean doing a separate update for each row.

Comment: so I just thought having to do the connect to db, disconnect, all the other stuff hundreds of tiems would be slower than delete and bulk insert, but maybe not?

Comment: while we're at it... are inserts generally much slower than updates?

Comment: Well the thing with inserts is that there is probably more latency, because the entire record's data has to be sent again to the database.  But if you can't do updates of multiple records for some reason, then maybe your approach is the only option.

Comment: I'll look further and see. So far, all I found was that their function insert() allows you to pass arrays of arrays to do a bulk insert, but their update() is set up for it to be a single array and then the WHERE part of it can be an array (or string or other types), which wouldn't work in this situation, since each row needs different changes. Maybe I missed something, though.